# proper usage of didn't had or didnt have

Tags: tenses

Its a simple ask as it doesn't appear to be wrong while using it in emails etc.

I didn't had breakfast or i didnt have breakfast.

Which one of above is better in grammatical manner.

Answer (score 11):

"I didn't have breakfast" is correct. After the auxiliary verb DO, we use the bare infinitive of the full verb, not a tensed form. "I didn't had breakfast" is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have is correct. The use of the auxiliary, to do, in negatives and interrogatives is always folllowed by the bare infinintive.

Answer (score -2):

HAD and HAVE can be quite interchangeable, they simply need wording correctly.

*'I've had no breakfast'* means the same as *'I didn't have breakfast'*
*'Did you have any breakfast?'* is the same as *'Have you had any breakfast?'*

A little tip is; *If HAVE-HAS use HAD.* i.e, They've had, you've had, we've, I've, He's, She's, It's etc.

Just be careful when it comes to Tense, and the meaning is different.
*'I have an idea',   'I had an idea'*